# matplotlib figures will not save in multiprocessing

Tags: python, matplotlib, multiprocessing, ipython

I am having trouble getting matplotlib figures to save within a process generated by multiprocessing. Based on numerous examples that I have found the following piece of test code ought to produce a file called: testfig.png, however, when this code is run in ipython the png file is never actually created.

```
    from multiprocessing import Process

    def makeplot():
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
        ax.plot([1,2,3],[3,4,5],'o')
        fig.savefig('testfig.png')
        plt.close()
        return None

    p = Process(target = makeplot)
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Comment: It works here (FreeBSD OS, AMD64 platform), both in IPython and in cpython. What OS are you using?

Comment: If you run `makeplot` without wrapping it does it create the file? Perhaps specify the full path to the file?

Comment: You could try using an absolute path in `savefig`. It could be that your process spawns with a different working directory (this doesn't happen on my machine, so this is just a shot in the dark).

Comment: Does the code work if you run it in standard python?

Comment: Thanks for the comments - I am running Python 2.7.3 | 64-bit on OS X 10.7.5. If I run makeplot in ipython it does create the file. Specifying the full path does not fix the issue. Finally - yes, when run in standard python the code works.

Comment: The issue was related to the use of pyfits, which had previously been imported into ipython. More details can be found here: https://github.com/spacetelescope/PyFITS/issues/38